# Convert php date() to mysql datatime format

Tags: php, mysql

I used "`$will = mktime($hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year)`" to build a time type, and i want translate `$will` to mysql datatime format, I tried to use `$mysqltime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $will);`
but when i insert it into msql, i can only get `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in the table.

Thanks in advance.

My code is like:

```
$mysqlpickuptime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime($hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year));
$mysqlrequestdata = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I collect these $hour, $minute... from a table which is no problem. and mysql statement is:

```
$SQLstatement1 ="INSERT INTO request(customer_id,**request_data**,item_description,weight,pick_up_address,pick_up_suburb,
        **pick_up_data**, receiver_name,delivery_address,delivery_suburb,state) VALUES ('".$customer_id."','".**$mysqlrequestdata**."','".$item_description."','".$weight."','".$pick_up_address."'
        ,'".$pick_up_suburb."','".**$mysqlpickuptime**."','".$receiver_name."','".$delivery_address."','".$delivery_suburb."','".$state."') ";
```

I tried suggestions shows blew, but still i get dataime column is 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

I am new to this system and php, sorry for confusion.

Comment: can you put your code in tags please.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($will);` ?

Comment: Just for reference, you may be glad to learn that php allows `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 'today + 30 days');`

Comment: please give us more code , how are you inserting the $mysqltime ?

Answer (score 0):

try this
     $dateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));

and next time try doing simple query on Google like "php date"

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i tried your code, but it's not work in mysql system, ill try it on google later.

Comment: try creating some demo code online so that we can help you in better way

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1 - use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` on databse layer

You can do this on the database side, using `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function (the argument is Unix epoch timestamp, so this is the same as the result of your `mktime()`).

used this `"INSERT INTO table_name (field) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME('$mysqltime')";`

### Solution 2 - fix your current code

Also your code is incorrect, because you pass incorrect date into `DateTime` constructor (see [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)). You pass `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` instead of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012))`. You can even resign from using `DateTime` and just stick to using `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012))`, as this is sufficient for your database insert.

Comment: thanks very much, but i tried date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012)), but it still shows 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

**Try Below Code:**

```
$formattedDateStr = date(
       "Y-m-d H:i:s",
       strtotime( "Mar 31 2013 01:04:47:687AM" ),
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know, if your mysql column is DATE, then use :

```
date('Y-m-d', mktime(....)) ;
```

Otherwise, if your column is DATETIME, you can fill all the date informations:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(...)) ;
```

Comment: I guess it's datetime according to his post "to mysql datatime format"

Comment: yes it's datatime type, but this date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(...)) ; still not in my sql..